# EF 4.3 Code First - Querying a navigation property backwards

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

I am trying to query a one to many relationship but cannot figure out how to do this.  The problem I have is that the ID of the field I want to filter by lives in the join table (not the main table)...

Its probably easier to illustrate rather than explain!!

The two classes I have are

```cs
public class DbUserClient
{
    public virtual string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual int ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime AssignedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? ClearedOn { get; set; }

    // navigation properties
    public virtual DbUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual DbClient Client { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class DbClient
{
    public virtual int ClientId {get;set;}
    public virtual string EntityName { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Deleted { get; set; }

    // navigation properties
    public ICollection<DbUserClient> UserClients { get; set; }
}
```

In the program I have a repository that exposes the Clients i.e.

```
    public ObservableCollection<DbClient> Clients
    {
        get { return context.Clients.Local; }
    }
```

I am binding to this which is why I am keen on querying via the Client as this will refresh my "Local" collection.  However I can't seem to figure out a way to include the UserClients as well as add the "where" clause.

I have tried something like

context.Clients.Include(c => c.UserClients.Where(uc => uc.UserId == "ME"));

But this results in the following exception
"*The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path*"

This works but unfortunately will not update my "Local" collection

```
from c in context.Clients
from uc in c.UserClients
where uc.ClientId == uc.ClientId && uc.UserId == "ME"
select new { c.ClientId, c.EntityName, uc.AssignedOn };
```

Any suggestions on where I have gone wrong?

Cheers
Abs

**EDIT I :** looking at the SQL Profiler the above query generates the following SQL

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ClientId] AS [ClientId], 
[Extent1].[EntityName] AS [EntityName], 
[Extent2].[AssignedOn] AS [AssignedOn]
FROM  [dbo].[Client] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserClient] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ClientId] = [Extent2].  [ClientId]
WHERE ([Extent2].[ClientId] = [Extent2].[ClientId]) AND (N'ME' = [Extent2].[UserId])
```

This is pretty simple and more or less along the lines of what I would have written myself if I was handcrafting the SQL

However although the suggested expression below works and as you pointed out populates the Local cache

```
context.Clients
  .Where(c => c.UserClients.Any(uc => uc.UserId == userId))
  .Select(c => new { DbClient = c, DbUser = c.UserClients.Where(uc => uc.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault() }).ToList();
```

it produces the following SQL.  This looks alot more complicated than it needs to be and I am assuming will have performance implications

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Filter2].[ClientId] AS [ClientId], 
[Filter2].[EntityName] AS [EntityName], 
[Filter2].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
[Limit1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
[Limit1].[ClientId] AS [ClientId1], 
[Limit1].[AssignedOn] AS [AssignedOn], 
[Limit1].[ClearedOn] AS [ClearedOn]
FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[ClientId] AS [ClientId], [Extent1].[EntityName] AS [EntityName], [Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted] 
    FROM [dbo].[Client] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[UserClient] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[ClientId] = [Extent2].[ClientId]) AND ([Extent2].[UserId] = @p__linq__0)
    ) ) AS [Filter2]
OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent3].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent3].[ClientId] AS [ClientId], 
    [Extent3].[AssignedOn] AS [AssignedOn], 
    [Extent3].[ClearedOn] AS [ClearedOn]
    FROM [dbo].[UserClient] AS [Extent3]
    WHERE ([Filter2].[ClientId] = [Extent3].[ClientId]) AND ([Extent3].[UserId] = @p__linq__1) ) AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'ME',@p__linq__1=N'ME'
```

**EDIT II :** After playing around some more, I have found a solution that seems to fulfill my requirement.  Looking at the SQL Profiler, I am happy with the generated SQL. This is similar to that of my orginal query.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[ClientId] AS [ClientId], 
[Extent1].[EntityName] AS [EntityName], 
[Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
[Extent2].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
[Extent2].[ClientId] AS [ClientId1], 
[Extent2].[AssignedOn] AS [AssignedOn], 
[Extent2].[ClearedOn] AS [ClearedOn]
FROM  [dbo].[Client] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserClient] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ClientId] = [Extent2].[ClientId]
WHERE [Extent2].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'ME'
```

I am assuming that there is no lazy loading involved here.  If someone could confirm I would be grateful

```
context.Clients.Join
  (
    context.UserClients, 
    c => c.ClientId, 
    uc => uc.ClientId, 
    (user, usrclient) => new { DbClient = user, DbUserClient = usrclient }
  ).Where(uc => uc.DbUserClient.UserId == userId).Load();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the clients which have at least one user with `UserId` = "ME":

```
var clients = context.Clients
    .Where(c => c.UserClients.Any(uc => uc.UserId == "ME"))
    .ToList();
```

This loads the correct clients but no user is included.

If you include the users...

```
var clients = context.Clients.Include(c => c.UserClients)
    .Where(c => c.UserClients.Any(uc => uc.UserId == "ME"))
    .ToList();
```

... you'll get the correctly filtered clients but it will include *all* users, not only the user "ME".

In order to get the users filtered as well your last approach, the projection, is the best way:

```
var clientsWithUser = context.Clients
    .Where(c => c.UserClients.Any(uc => uc.UserId == "ME"))
    .Select(c => new
    {
        Client = c,
        User = c.UserClients.Where(uc => uc.UserId == "ME").FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .ToList();
```

This should also update the `Local` collection because you are loading full entities (`Client` and `User`) in the anonymous object list.

**Edit**

The last query in your question is fine, although it's not really the EF way to write a Join manually when you have navigation properties. The SQL and query result is most likely identical to:

```
context.UserClients.Include(uc => uc.Client)
    .Where(uc => uc.UserId == userId)
    .Load();
```

The `Include` in this query should translate into the same `INNER JOIN` that your hand-written LINQ `Join` produces.

Comment: Thanks for the taking the time to look into this.  I wasn't sure what the best way was to comment on your suggestions so I have added an EDIT section to my original post.  If you could please take a peek at it and let me know your thoughts

Comment: @user1460473: I've added a brief Edit section to my answer.